# axis ticks of autoplot object

Tags: r, workflow, supervised-learning, tidymodels

In the example to compare plot model results from many different resampled `tidymodels`, how can I change the labels of the x-axis ticks?

```
autoplot(
   grid_results,
   rank_metric = "rmse",  # <- how to order models
   metric = "rmse",       # <- which metric to visualize
   select_best = TRUE     # <- one point per workflow
)
```

I have tried it for instance with  `+ scale_x_discrete(labels = rep("example", 12))` as an extension to the autoplot object but the plots did not show any labels in this case.

The example refers to the first image under [this link](https://www.tmwr.org/workflow-sets.html#tuning-and-evaluating-the-models), heading: **15.3 TUNING AND EVALUATING THE MODELS**

Comment: Try with `scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:12, labels = rep("example", 12))`. From the picture in the link you posted I would guess that the x -axis var is a numeric.

Comment: thank you. My bad, I didn't realise. Because I am unfamiliar with ``autoplot``, I distracted my search by looking for solutions within the options of ``autoplot``.

Comment: The `autoplot()` output is a `ggplot` object so you should be able to use (most) ggplot2 functions to modify it, like to change the title, theme, and other characteristics.

Comment: Thank you so much! Relatedly, I was wondering how I can adapt the labels of facet wraps when plotting several metrics at once. It seems that wen using ``autoplot`` and ``facet_wrap`` to change the labels with ``labeller``, it is difficult for me to access the nested elements in the metrics list and specifically the metric column. Any suggestions how to approach this?